# Delete_if over an array with strings and numbers, Refactored

Tags: ruby, loops, refactoring

I'm confused as to why the following will not work.

```
def array_mod(source_array, letter_to_delete)
  source_array.delete_if {|x| 
    String===x && x.include?letter_to_delete }
end
```

Essentially I have a function which accepts an array, which, for testing purposes will have both strings and numbers. The second parameter is a letter. The function should iterate over the array, skip the Fixnum values, and delete_if the elements which are a) strings and b) contain the offending letter. I've created this function already but am trying to refactor it to make it more professional. Thank you guys for helping me get better!

```
def array_mod(source_array, letter_to_delete)
  return source_array.delete_if do |x| 
      if x.is_a?(Fixnum) ==true
        next
      else
        x.include?letter_to_delete
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the line `if x.is_a?(Fixnum) ==true`. If I were you I will make it like this instead: `if (x.is_a?(Fixnum) ==true)==true`. Just to be sure. Hehe.. JK. You can just leave it until `if x.is_a?(Fixnum)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis:

```
def array_mod(source_array, letter_to_delete)
  source_array.delete_if {|x| x.is_a?(String) && x.include?(letter_to_delete) }
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason the String===x not acceptable? My understanding is that that just means 'x' is of type 'string' which is the same as x.is_a?(String) no?

Comment: @HectorOfTroy407 - You're correct, I prefer to use `is_a?` since it is more obvious and to leave `===` for case statements.

Comment: Being the forgetful sort, I might write `str===String` and possibly have tough bug to find.  I'm less likely to write `String.is_a? str`.  (I sometimes write `=~` as `~=` and `||=` as `=||`).